# Custom Adapter not displaying listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-adapter

My custom adapter won't print out the ListView. In my code, I am taking JSON input from a URL and parsing it to display in my custom ListView.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ArrayList<String> workList;

    String title;
    String imagepathview;
    String description;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        workList = new ArrayList<>();

        new GetWork().execute();
    }

    private class GetWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Work...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Context context;

            // URL to get JSON data
            String url = "http:xyz.json";


            FirstAccessInDay f = new FirstAccessInDay(); //Makes HTTPHandler call and returns the JSON.
            String jsonStr = f.firstaccess(url);

             workList = null;
            JSONArray a;
            String key;

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    workList = new ArrayList<>();

                    Iterator iterator = jsonObj.keys();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        key = (String) iterator.next();

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        a = jsonObj.getJSONArray(key); 

                        int j = 0;

                                JSONObject c = a.getJSONObject(j);
                                JSONObject d = a.getJSONObject(j + 1);
                                JSONObject e = a.getJSONObject(j + 2);

                                title = c.getString("title");
                                imagepathview = d.getString("image");
                                description = e.getString("description");


                                workList.add(title);
                                workList.add(imagepathview);
                                workList.add(description);

                       }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.mylist,workList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomListAdapter.java:

```
class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Adapter {

    private final Activity context;
    private ArrayList worklist;

    static  class ViewHolder{
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView extratxt;
    }

    CustomListAdapter(Activity context, int listViewId, ArrayList worklist) {
        super(context, listViewId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context = context;
        this.worklist = worklist;

    }

    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
         View rowView= view;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = null;


            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
                rowView.setTag(holder);
            }
        else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }
                String title = (String)worklist.get(position);
                holder.txtTitle.setText(title);

                String imagepathview = (String)worklist.get(position);
                imageLoader.displayImage(imagepathview, holder.imageView);

                String description = (String) worklist.get(position);
                holder.extratxt.setText(description);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

This is my LogCat:

```
    Process pipe failed

                                                                          [ 03-01 14:36:02.192  4772: 4806 D/         ]
                                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f04c6b3e020, tid 4806
03-01 14:36:02.203 4772-4806/com.example.customlistview I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-01 14:36:02.265 4772-4806/com.example.customlistview E/EGL_emulation: tid 4806: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-01 14:36:02.266 4772-4806/com.example.customlistview W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f04bde0b2c0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
03-01 14:36:02.347 4772-4806/com.example.customlistview E/EGL_emulation: tid 4806: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-01 14:36:02.347 4772-4806/com.example.customlistview W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f04bde0b300, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
03-01 14:36:03.937 4772-4806/com.example.customlistview E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f04bf6d0a80
03-01 14:36:03.959 4772-4772/com.example.customlistview D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-01 14:36:03.968 4772-4772/com.example.customlistview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.customlistview, PID: 4772
                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.customlistview.ModelClass
                                                                              at com.example.customlistview.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:73)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-01 14:36:06.429 4772-4772/com.example.customlistview I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4772 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first set **getCount()**  Method

```
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return worklist.size();
    }
```

Make sure that your **workList.size()** return **0 or else**.

Create a model class

```
 public class ModelClass implements Serializable{

    public String title, description,image;

    public ModelClass()
    {

    }
    public ModelClass(String title, String description,String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;


    }


    public String get_title() {
        return this.title;
    }
    public String get_description() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public String get_image() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void set_title(String title){this.id = title;}
    public void set_description(String description){this.description = description;}
    public void set_image(String image){this.image = image;}

}
```

**Declare**

```
ArrayList<ModelClass> al_Test      = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();
```

Then

```
ModelClass test_Obj = new ModelClass(title,imagepathview,description);
al_Test.add(test_Obj);
```

**Goto Adapter**

```
 String title =worklist.get(position).get_title();
            holder.txtTitle.setText(title);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137138/discussion-on-answer-by-intellij-amiya-custom-adapter-not-displaying-listview).